# Do we have to use SF Symbols for designing native iOS apps?

Tags: user-experience, sf-symbols

I have just finished my UX design course and I am building up my portfolio. I have designed a web app that I need to redesign as a native app for iOS and Android (it won't be developed as it's not a real project).

My question is can I use the icons I have designed for the web app for the native iOS version, or do I absolutely have to use [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) (I am working on a PC and downloading SF Symbols seems impossible).

How would you go about it in the real world where the app has to be developed for both platforms?

I will be grateful for your help. Thank you!

Comment: Font Awesome, IcoFont might be something to look into, for cross platform work. Though it is not Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not require developers to use SF Symbols. Apple’s [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) say that “SF Symbols provides a set of over 2,400 consistent, highly configurable symbols you can use in your app”. That means they can be used, but it is not a requirement. There are many examples of apps on the app store which do not use them.

In my particular experience, I’m developing an app where we use SF Symbols for some of the icons, and others we get them from other sources or we design them ourselves.

I do think Apple’s intention in providing SF Symbols is that as developers start using them, it will provide a somewhat more consistent visual experience for users across apps. But in no way it’s a requirement.

As a personal advice, use an SF Symbols icon only if it’s directly meaningful for the function you are providing. If none of the SF Symbols work for that particular function, it’s better to design your own icon or to look elsewhere than to “stretch” the meaning of an SF Symbol.